# Return a char pointer with multiple possible values

Tags: c, pointers, char

The aim of the following function consists to retrieve specifics information 
by calling few functions which are returning gchar * (using glib for D-BUS object parsing).
get_param() will be used in another file to get and work with these values.

```
 char * get_param(unsigned short ID)
 {
     char * value = NULL;

     if(ID == 0x01)
     {
         value = get_revision(); // REV 04.012
     }
     else if(ID == 0x02)
     {
         value = get_pin(); // 0000
     }
     else if(ID == 0x03)
     {
         value = get_identifier(); // 690012345396789
     }
     else if(ID == 0x04)
     {
         value = get_number(); // 697132101234585233318
     }
     else if(ID == 0x05)
     {
         value = get_manufacturer(); // MANUFACTURER_1
     }
     else {}

     return value;
 }
```

I get the expected values in the final source file, but I will probably get bad behavior by returning 
char * without memory allocation. In this specific case, data length isn't know in advance, so it is 
better to allocate a size more bigger as necessary or not ? Should I define my function as returning void 
type and include char ** in its arguments ?

EDIT : (to give more information)

I will take `get_pin()` function as example. 
This function returns a gchar * which has been initialized by using `gchar * output = g_strdup (g_variant_get_string(myVariant, NULL))`. According to the gnome datasheet `g_strdup returns a newly-allocated` copy of myVariant. 
Then, in the final function I would define an array as `char value[50]` and initialize it by using `value = get_param(0x01)`

Comment: If you are returning a pointer there is nothing to allocate.  A pointer points at allocated memory.  The function that is returning the pointer needs to allocate memory.

Comment: It all depends on how you use the returned pointer, and of course what pointer the functions you call return (for example if they return a pointer to a local non-static array you're in trouble). Without knowing more it's hard to say anything specific.

Comment: It *looks* that you are likely returning a pointer to string literals, statically allocated in the memory. In this case you are fine. But it is just a guess. You have to tell us what these getters are doing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have edited the post to give more information about variable usage. Thank for your clarification

Comment: about the update: `strdup` is allocating the memory. You should `free` it at some point. You better free it every time *before* calling your `get_param`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Indeed, you confirmed my idea about `strdup`. If `get_pin()` (same for others functions) defines its variable as `gchar * output = NULL` following by `output = g_strdup (g_variant_get_string(myVariant, NULL))` instead of `gchar * output = g_strdup (g_variant_get_string(myVariant, NULL))` could it be considered as a free at each occurence of  `get_param` ?

Comment: No it can't. It will allocate it every time it is called

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok I understand now, but how to `free` this specific memory before calling `get_param()` It is equivalent to perform a memset() on the array named `value` and defined as `char value[50]` isn't ?  (see the Edit)

Comment: About the update: It won't work. You cant assign arrays like this.

Answer (score 1):

In nowadays standards, you should use externally allocated memory, and length limit, like all the *_r functions do. See gethostbyname_r.

All other alternatives are lacking. If you allocate every time you force users to dealocate which is less than comfortable.
You allocate and reuse the same memory per thread but, in your case, since you're dealing with various return values, the contents of the memory would change under your clients feet so very unadvisable.

Using externally allocated memory also gives them the option to allocate the memory in other ways than plain malloc.

Answer (score -1):

Currently you are returning a pointer to already allocated value, so there's no bad practice.

If you'd really want to allocate memory for theses pointers, you could do something like that :

```
 ...
 char* returned_value = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(value) + 1));
 strcpy(returned_value, value);
 return return_value;
```

Of course, you should trust that the value actually contains a `\0` in a reasonnable length.

Comment: Somebody would have to free this allocated memory. Got to document that etc. Nowadays you're supposed to use the *_r functions and provide externally allocated memory